# Not able to reading utf-8 file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8

I am reading a file with utf-8 encoding. Below is my code.

```
QFile file("file.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
  return 1;
}
QTextStream ts(&file);
ts.setCodec( "UTF-8" );
QString str = ts.readLine();    
qDebug() << str << str.toUtf8().toHex();
```

output: "??" "f09d9c86"

file contain only one character:   i.e.Lambda
unicode value of Lambda is 3bb and its utf equivalent is cebb 
then why am i getting output as f09d9c86

when i hardcode the string in code i get correct result.

```
QString str = QString::fromWCharArray(L"");
qDebug() << str << str.toUtf8().toHex();
```

am I doing something wrong? please help.

Comment: How certain are you of your file contents? (Copy/pasting that char from the browser to an utf-8 console doesn't work well.) Can you inspect your input file with a hex editor or  `hexdump -C`?

Comment: qDebug() isn't a good way to test encoding. What ends up on the console depends on many factors, including the configuration of the shell etc. Better test by displaying it in a QWidget.

Answer (score 4):

The UTF-8 representation of  (U+1D706 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL LAMDA) is `f0 9d 9c 86`.